# 'Could not handle the request' error in GCP function to connect to Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-functions

I was writing my first GCP function to connect to postgresql and fetch some data. When executed via the trigger url, I get error as

```
Error: could not handle the request
```

The same code while running from local system connecting to the same database works fine

Below is the code

```
 const express = require('express');
 const app = express();
 const Pool = require('pg').Pool
 const pool = new Pool({
   user: 'postgres',
   host: 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx',
   database: 'postgres',
   password: 'mypasswordxxxx',
   port: 5432,
 })
 
 
 app.get('/', (req,res,next) =>  {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM leads', (error, results) => {
     if (error) {
       throw error
     }
     res.status(200).json(results.rows)
   })
 });
 
 
 module.exports = {
     app
 };
```

When I analyze the log it says "Function execution took 60003 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'". But I have also tried increasing my function timeout to maximum value

Comment: Well: maybe it is not responding. Maybe there is a firewall or proxy between your client and the server, ...

Comment: No, there is no proxy or firewall enabled

Comment: Do you use Cloud SQL or a custom PostgreSQL?

Comment: Adding to guillaume's comment, is there a connectivity path to the postgres instance from the Cloud Function?     
Please include all the steps you have followed to set up your postgres instance.          
If the function is timing out, it might be because there is no connectivity path to the target postgres instance.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I use PostgreSQL

Comment: Is your PostgreSQL server deployed on Google Cloud? Do you use a public or private IP to reach it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved when I used instance connection name instead of IP address. Don't know why! But at least I know the solution now :-). Thanks everyone for responding to my question